# Java Reflection invoking method NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to invoking a method from a class which the name of that class is given by the user.
The program looks like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String className = in.nextLine();
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    Object myObj = c.newInstance();
    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("equals", new String("test").getClass());
    Object retn = m.invoke(myObj, new String("testing").getClass());
}
}
```

I'm trying to execute this program by giving the input:
java.lang.String

But I always get NoSuchMethodException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.String)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2122)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

And I know that the method equals is declared in the class java.lang.String. So what am I doing wrong?

I hid the try catch blocks because I didn't think it was necessary to express my doubt here.
Hopefully someone can help me.

EDIT:

Say now that i wanted to execute the method:
    getDeclaredConstructors 
On the class i receieved. I would only have to change the program to:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String className = in.nextLine();
    Class c = Class.forName(className);
    Object myObj = c.newInstance();
    Method m = c.getMethod("getDeclaredConstructor");
    Object retn = m.invoke(myObj);
    System.out.println(retn);
}
}
```

? If i do this i get the same exception. What am i doing wrong in this case?

Comment: `equals(String _)` is not declared on `String` and `Class<? extends String>` is not a `String` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to invoke the `equals(String)` method in the `String` class, which does not exist.  The method to invoke is [`equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Pass `Object.class` as the parameter type to `getDeclaredMethod`.

```
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("equals", Object.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Another question: if i wanted to invoke the method: getDeclaredConstructors on this class, how could i do it? Because it gives me the same exception i guess because the method is defined in a super class?

Comment: You can always call `getDeclaredConstructors` on any `Class` object.

Comment: So in order to do that, i would only have to do:

    Method m = c.getMethod("getDeclaredConstructors");
    Object retn = m.invoke(myObj);
    System.out.println(retn);

? Because i got the same exception as before. Sorry for insisting here, i appreciate any help you can give

Comment: The `String` class doesn't have the method `getDeclaredConstructors`; the `Class` class has that method.

Comment: So i need to access the super class? I'm not following here. Could you please post a sample code if thats not much too ask?